# Magento 2 : How to detect if payment has failed

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, payment, paypal, debugging

How can I check a payment process failed while ordering in Magento 2?

I want to set some logic if payment failed during order placing. Payment can be done from any payment method like PayPal, debit card, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When any payment method from Magento is called it gathers the transaction information back from the payment module using `rest/default/V1/carts/mine/payment-information` API, this can be seen the network tab of any browser's console. You can check the response code and response of the specific request to determine whether the payment was successful or not.

For advanced debugging ofcource, you'll have set up an Xdebug trace or add a logger in payment method's model class. But, for the general purpose, you will also get the error message too in case an exception has occurred during the transaction.

Comment: Thanks for guiding.Can you please tell me where I can set my code in which module in which class path of that file where put my code to detect.

Comment: It depends on the specific payment method you want to debug. You asked a general question above so I gave a general answer.

Comment: i am using paypal but did't get where to detect if it failed

Comment: Did you get any message in the network tab of dev console?

Comment: Also check system and exception log after placing the order

Comment: no I am not getting anything

Comment: If you're not getting anything there you may want to check the transaction in the merchant account.

Comment: actually I want to block those IP who failed to payment for three times in one minute .So i want to catch the situation when it fis a failed attempt.But i can cant find any thing where set my condition.

Comment: You should have asked a completely different question man. But I am gonna give you some reference still - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/fmf/integration-guide/FMFSummary/ . Please look into IP Address Velocity Filter it will fulfill your requirement.

Comment: Thank you i will check on it

Comment: Please accept the answer if it answered your original query.